# Who has to pay zakat on wife's gold?

Tags: zakat

My wife has gold, which was given to her by her brother on our wedding. My question is, who needs to pay the zakat on that gold if the husband doesn't have enough income to pay it on behalf of his wife?

Comment: @azam Related but different question. The OP may chose the opinion of Zatakable gold and in that case who pays it is important, which isn't covered by the linked question.